# Discord bot image does not show up

Tags: javascript, image, png, discord, discord.js

I am trying to send an image using discord.js, but the image shows up as a downloadable file instead of the actual image

I have tried using the same method but with a url that ends in .jpg or .png and it works. This link is a png image but it doesn't have the extension

```
client.on('message', (msg) => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.channel.send("new message ", {file: 
          "https://www.tradingview.com/x/uNzxW3Is"});
   }
});
```

Comment: Sounds like it could just be a bug with discod.js. Did you find any relevant issues on its Github page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specify file name, it works correctly:

```
msg.channel.send({
  files: [{
    attachment: 'https://www.tradingview.com/x/uNzxW3Is',
    name: 'file.jpg'
  }]});
```

Apparently the library is not smart enough to convert the file to desired extension automatically (or perhaps not supposed to do so), so you have to specify that it's an image.

Also, it's worth mentioning, that `file` property of `MessageOptions` is [deprecated](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions), so you should use `files` instead.